# Convolution neural networks?

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, neural-network, convolution, conv-neural-network

Okay I am starting to understand the idea of neural networks but I still haven't been able to understand the use/benefits/implementation of convolutional neural networks especially for image processing.

What I don't understand is how to detect an object of different size.

Say we have a weights matrix of 50*50 and a face in the training set which is of 50*50 size .
Now when you take the weighted sum of the matrix it will return a particular value say "X" .
So now I understand the idea is to run the weights matrix over the entire image to get a lock over a region which gives a weighted sum of ~"X" now you have detected a face.

If the above mentioned understanding is true   Then how is that an image of size 25*25 going to churn out a value anywhere clone to "X" . So the basic question is how to deal with relative sizes of the image .

If possible please suggest some good tutorials for the same .

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097111/newbie-convolutional-neural-networks-vs-downsampling/38098142#38098142) and yours popped up, therefore a couple of thoughts although this is an older question:

- usually you have more than one weight matrix (i.e. several layers) in a neural network, therefore 'getting a lock over a region' is often too simplistic. Features that are 'important' to neural networks can be complex.
- one of the main features of convolutional networks is simplifying and 'downsampling' the weight matrices (called pooling) as stated in the answer to my similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097111/newbie-convolutional-neural-networks-vs-downsampling/38098142#38098142).
- Inputs to a neural network to recognize images can vary widely, you do not always need a pixel-by-pixel input. Among many one of the reductions you can make is using vectors laid over an image ([read more here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11285/Neural-Network-OCR#pre900901)).
- Here's a [link to a good tutorial](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#layers) that was suggested to me / helped me a lot