# Convolutional neural networks vs downsampling?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

After reading up on the subject I don't fully understand: **Is the 'convolution' in neural networks comparable to a simple downsampling or 'sharpening' function?**

Can you break this term down into a simple, understandable image/analogy?

**edit: Rephrase after 1st answer: Can pooling be understood as downsampling of weight matrices?**

Comment: popular question with no upvotes, I can only presume people come here and are disappointed in the question or answers. Make sure to leave a comment so any misleading phrasing can be corrected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Convolutional neural network** is a family of models which are proved empirically to work great when it comes to image recognition. From this point of view - **CNN** is something completely different than downsampling.

But in framework used in **CNN** design there is something what is comparable to a downsampling technique. To fully understand that - you have to understand how **CNN** usually works. It is build by a hierarchical number of layers and at every layer you have a set of a trainable kernels which output has a dimension very similiar to spatial size of your input images.

This might be a serious problem - the output from such layer might be extremely huge (`~ nr_of_kernels * size_of_kernel_output`) which could make your computations intractable. This is the reason why a certain techniques are used in order to decrease size of the output:

1. **Stride, pad and kernel size manipulation:** be setting these values to a certain value you could decrese the size of the output (on the other hand - you may lose some of important information).
2. **Pooling operation:** pooling is an operation in which instead of passing as an output from a layer all outputs from all kernels - you might pass only specific aggregated statistics about it. It is considered as extremely useful and is widely used in **CNN** design.

For a detailed description you might visit this [tutorial](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#layers).

**Edit:** Yes, pooling is a kind of downsampling

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what I'm asking better somewhat better (I will also checkout the tutorial). The question now would be, can the pooling part be understood as downsampling of the weight matrices.